# What HTTP response code is more appropriate if user provided wrong registration code?

Tags: http, response, registration

I'm building an app where users can only register if they provide a valid registration code that is stored in my database. So I want to send them an appropriate HTTP response if such code is not in the database. Should I use 400, 403 or 404?

I tried to google this but could not find my specific case, only "wrong password" or "wrong login" type of questions.

Comment: 403 Authentication required.

Comment: Is the registration code sent as part of the URL or in POST-submitted parameters?

Comment: Daniel Martin, it's in the POST body.

Comment: This probably shouldn't be reported as an error at the HTTP layer to begin with.  I would suggest returning an HTTP 200 response containing a JSON or XML document in its body, and have that document contain a success/failure status and an error message if needed.

Comment: @user207421. You're mixing 2 status codes. It does sound to be like like `403 Forbidden` though.